# Creating a Substring of text from query results for a Visual Studio report

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I am trying to create a substring from query results that are dates. I am hoping to use this in a late payment notice I am creating in Visual Studio SSRS.  My query basic query is:

```
    select Distinct a.inv_date
    from PastDue_Master a
    left join
    PastDue_Mmbr_List b on a.ID_NUM = b.ID_NUM
    where (DAYS_PAST_DUE >= 30 and [60d_Notice_Date] is null)
    and Crctd_Inv_Flag = 0
    and Facility_Name = 'Facility Name'
```

with a result set of

```
2019-02-28 00:00:00.000  
2019-05-31 00:00:00.000  
2019-08-31 00:00:00.000  
2019-11-30 00:00:00.000
```

I have tried the following:

```
 Declare @datestring varchar (8000)
 select @datestring = stuff((select ',' +convert(nvarchar(20), SNAF_Inv_Date)
 FROM PastDue_Master a
 left join PastDue_Mmbr_List b on a.ID_NUM = b.ID_NUM
 where (DAYS_PAST_DUE >= 30 and [60d_Notice_Date] is null)
 and Crctd_Inv_Flag = 0
 and Facility_Name = 'Facility Name' FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')
```

but I get "Commands completed successfully." with no result set I am looking for

```
02/28/2019, 05/31/2019, 08/31/2019, 11/30/2019
```

Comment: Your results are going to the variable datestring .  You can select @datestring when the query is done to inspect the results

Comment: You can use cast(SNAF_Inv_Date as date)  to remove the timepart of the datetime field.

Comment: When you select into variables there is no result set.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to @datestring but not using @datestring in your code. If you added: `SELECT @datestring` or `PRINT @datestring` you would see something returned.

Note this code:

```
DECLARE @demo TABLE (dt VARCHAR(30));
INSERT @demo VALUES
('2019-02-28 00:00:00.000'),  
('2019-05-31 00:00:00.000'),  
('2019-08-31 00:00:00.000'),  
('2019-11-30 00:00:00.000');

DECLARE @datestring VARCHAR(8000);

SELECT @datestring =  STUFF((
  SELECT CONCAT(' ,',IIF(MONTH(f.Dt)<10,'0',''),MONTH(f.Dt) ,'/',DAY(f.Dt),'/',YEAR(f.Dt))
  FROM   @demo AS d
  CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CAST(d.Dt AS DATE))) AS f(Dt)
  FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'');

SELECT @datestring;
PRINT @datestring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning to a single `varchar` variable which you are then using separately, you don't need any fancy expensive in-line concatenation, you can simply do:

```
declare @datestring varchar(max)='';
select @datestring+=',' + Convert(varchar(10),inv_date,101)
from a /* Insert your required query here */

set @datestring=Stuff(@datestring,1,1,'');

select @datestring;
```